How to write IF Then, Else formula
I'm making a simple Google Sheets spreadsheet to track income and expenses.
I need a formula to do the following
if 
   sum(B21:C22) > 204
then
    D2 = sum(B21:C22)-204)/2
else
    D2 = sum(B21:C22)
end if

